# Codeigniter 2.1 - join two tables and count in the same query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have two tables:

```
news ->     
  id_news    
  title    
  body    
  date_created    
  image    
  category_id    

comments ->     
  id_comments    
  news_id    
  body    
  date_created
```

How can I write query to get all news, count all the comments for every news and present that query in the view part?

Comment: Could you paste the structure of your tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
      N.ID_News,
      N.Title,
      N.Body,
      N.Date_Created,
      N.Image,
      N.Category_ID,
      count(C.ID_Comments) CommentCount
   from
      News N
         LEFT JOIN Comments C
            on N.ID_News = C.News_ID
   group by 
      N.ID_News
   order by
      whatever column(s) are important to you
```

Comment: Sorry to keep you waiting. This is working, but I get only one news, not all. I guess this is because only one news has comments at this time or it doesn't matter?

Comment: It does not matter, @DRapp is using LEFT JOIN

Comment: @m4t1t0 what could be the problem then? (After the query I have this part **$q = $this->db->query($q);** **return $q = $q->result_array();**). Does this matter?

Comment: No, it should not be the problem. Could you put your code of how you've traslated the query by @DRapp using Code Igniter Active Record?

Comment: @m4t1t0 Suthan bala modified the answer a bit and now it is working,

Answer (score 1):

Since we are counting, we need to make a minor change to DRap's Query:

```
select
      N.ID_News,
      N.Title,
      N.Body,
      N.Date_Created,
      N.Image,
      N.Category_ID,
      count(C.ID_Comments) CommentCount
   from
      News N
         LEFT JOIN Comments C
            on N.ID_News = C.News_ID
   order by
      whatever column(s) are important to you
```

That will only give you only one result.. as that query lacks a group by statement, I would recommend changing that query to this:

```
select
      N.ID_News,
      N.Title,
      N.Body,
      N.Date_Created,
      N.Image,
      N.Category_ID,
      count(C.ID_Comments) CommentCount
   from
      News N
         LEFT JOIN Comments C
            on N.ID_News = C.News_ID
   group by
      N.title
   order by
      whatever column(s) are important to you
```

Comment: Suthan, for future, on something so minor of a change in an offered answer, it's typically common to just put a comment on that person's answer to make the fix.  I was quick in the response, skipped the group by... @Sasha, However, this revision could also fail if you have say 5 titles by same description.  The group by SHOULD be by the "ID" of the news article.

Comment: okay sorry, i tried to reply under your post, but for I don't see the add comment button there. Thank you.

Comment: @DRapp Advice taken an implemented :).

Answer (score 0):

Writing this down in the Active Record format stays something like this:

```
$this->db->select('N.ID_News, N.Title, N.Body, N.Date_Created, N.Image')
$this->db->select('N.Category_ID, count(C.ID_Comments) AS CommentCount');
$this->db->from('News AS N');
$this->db->join('commentas AS C', 'N.ID_News = C.News_ID', 'left');
$this->db->group_by('N.title');
```

After this you can use the order by funtion, to order the resultsas you seefit.